# How was the Emacs Manual typed?

Tags: documentation, manual

I have a beautiful hardcopy of the Emacs Manual printed by the FSF. I was wondering if anyone knew how this document was created in Emacs and what mode was used for its creation? I would also be interested to know how the effect of the different fonts was achieved? I am assuming it was typed up in Emacs and that Richard Stallman was the person to have typed it. There does not appear to be specific information in the Manual itself on the process.

Comment: And now I want to get one of these, but alas, the international shipping is horrendous!

Comment: It's worth the expense!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was typed in texinfo. See here: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq/Getting-a-printed-manual.html